# Show username after login success

Tags: php, mysql

i try different ways to get the username to display after logging in successfully.
Got it to login, but not to display the usernamename.
does anybody have a tip? 
In my login.success.php I now got only this after trying several things.:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "header.inc.php";
include "funksjoner.inc.php";
?>
```

in my check_login.php I got this:

```
<?php if($count==1){
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
header("location:login_success.php" );
?>
```

I can paste out more of the script if its necessary.
Grateful if someone can lighten me up on this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session_register()` is depreciated. You can set session variable using `$_SESSION['username']="username";` It will be accessible in login_success.php. You just have to do `echo "Logged in as".$_SESSION['username'];`

Comment: i changed this in_login.php: $_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;

Comment: and this in login_success.php  <?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['mypassword']="myusername";
echo "Innlogget inn som".$_SESSION['myusername'];

Comment: Mark answer if this was useful :)